# Using placeholder audio while animating?

Tags: audio

I was wondering if there's a way to hear audio when going through the timeline. So, if I animated a character talking between frames 0 and 40, when playing the animation not only I can see the movement in the viewport but hear the sound.

Thanks in advance.